# Remove duplicate records in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table called `leads` with duplicate records

```
Leads:
*account_id
*campaign_id
```

I want to remove all the duplicate `account_id` where `campaign_id equal to "51"`

For example, if `account_id = 1991` appears two times in the table then remove the one with `campaign_id = "51"` and keep the other one.

Comment: could you post a small subset of data in leads table? also apart from these 2 are there any other columns(like timestamp or id) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mcve]" and their linked pages. We'd like to see evidence of your effort toward solving the problem. WIthout that it looks like you want us to find you documentation or a tutorial, or write code for you, all of which are off-topic. You need to write code, then, when you encounter a problem, ask a specific question about that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a delete join:

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.account_id = t1.account_id AND
       t2.campaign_id <> 51
WHERE
    t1.campaign_id = 51;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem to delete from a table provided that:

1. You use the correct syntax.
2. You have done a backup of the table BEFORE you do any deleting.

However, I would suggest a different method:

1. Create a new table based on the existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_new LIKE mytable;
```

2. Add unique constraint (or `PRIMARY KEY`) on column(s) you don't want to have duplicates:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable_new ADD UNIQUE(column1,[column2]);
```

Note: if you want to identify a combination of two (or more) columns as unique, place all the column names in the `UNIQUE()` separated by comma. Maybe in your case, the constraint would be `UNIQUE(account_id, campaign_id)`.

3. Insert data from original table to new table:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable_new SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Note: the `IGNORE` will insert only non-duplicate values that match with the `UNIQUE()` constraint. If you have an app that runs a MySQL `INSERT` query to the table, you have to update the query by adding `IGNORE`.

4. Check data consistency and once you're satisfied, rename both tables:

```
RENAME TABLE mytable TO mytable_old;
RENAME TABLE mytable_new TO mytable;
```

The best thing about this is that in case that if you see anything wrong with the new table, you still have the original table.

Changing the name of the tables only take less than a second, the probable issue here is that it might take a while to do the `INSERT IGNORE` if you have a large data.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UqeyqmE5)

Answer (score 0):

DELETE t1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
ON t2.account_id = t1.account_id AND
t2.campaign_id <> 51
WHERE
t1.campaign_id = 51;